# Fixed colormap to values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot of data over time in matplotlib - one of the features I have in the chart is having a color of bubble based on value which goes from 32.5 to 50.
To make things clear, I normalized it so values go in the range [0, 1].

```
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(32.5, 50)
colors = [[norm(32.5), "red"],
          [norm(40), "salmon"],
          [norm(42.5), "yellow"],
          [norm(45), "limegreen"],
          [norm(47.5), "green"],
          [norm(50), "darkgreen"]]

my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", colors)

dix_array = np.array(df_sel['DIX 10MA'])
normalized_dix = (dix_array - min(dix_array)) / (max(dix_array) - min(dix_array))
```

The problem I have is that the bubble colors change depending on the timeframe I choose - the colormap is not directly assigned to values but it does a relative mapping based on the values in the selection on the chart. Is there a way to keep thing like that eg value of 45 will be of limegreen color no matter how long period I choose?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=10, nrows=8, figsize=(16, 9))
.
.
axbig1.scatter(number_index, df_sel["SPYClose"], s=normalized_gex*500, c=normalized_dix, cmap=my_cmap)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add how exactly you call the bubble chart. Probably you to provide the same norm() to that function.

Comment: If you calculate normalized_dix yourself, you need to use the same norm (instead of using min and max). And tell scatter() to not normalize again. But can just call scatter() with the original data and let it do the normalization with the same `norm`

Comment: Ah, scatter auto-normalization what the culprit. I had no idea it is done automatically, I thought it was off on default. Adding vmax and vmin into scatter helped. Thanks.